How should I go about completely decorrelating a digital signal?
So I'm working on real time signal compression, and I need to come up with the best convolution to minimize the entropy of incoming data (which I will then compress), which I understand is achieved by applying a convolution that decorrelates the data completely (minimizes autocorrelation). I'm also aware some people call this "Signal Whitening" .
As I currently understand it, the continuous version of this problem has been solved, which involves "normalizing" the power spectral density and then applying a reverse Fourier transform. In the discrete case, I believe that the problem lies with approximating this power spectral density distribution given a finite set of datapoints.
Do you know of any good techniques that completely decorrelate (or comes very close to it) finite data? Is my assumption correct that this is a solved problem in the continuous case, but has computational issues in the discrete case? Furthermore, would it be fair to assume that calculating the convolution beforehand and using it on new data from the same source would also result in good decorrelation? Are there any good libraries that automatically do this?
I may be wrong in many of my assumptions so far, and for that I apologize. I'm quite new to the field. I would really appreciate any corrections to my knowledge.

no, wait, you seem to have this backwards: if you whiten the signal, you keep its data size, but make it harder to compress. Usually the opposite of what you want to do: your entropy coder (source coder) needs to find ways the signal is correlated and exploit these, to produce a reduced-length data stream that contains the same information as the original signal. This compression: that is the process that decorrelates. You abhor doing it before!

From Data Compression: The Complete Reference by Bryant (ch. 4, pp. 261): “Approach 5: Transform the values of the pixels and encode the transformed values.
Recall that compression is achieved by reducing or removing redundancy. The redundancy of an image is caused by the correlation between pixels, so transforming the pixels to a representation where they are decorrelated eliminates the redundancy. It is also possible to think of a transform in terms of the entropy of the image. In a highly correlated image, the pixels tend to have equiprobable values, which results in maximum entropy.” …

(Cntd from the previous comment): “If the transformed pixels are decorrelated, certain pixel values become common, thereby having large probabilities, while others are rare. This results in small entropy.“

I think that your understanding of the problem is quite solid. Signal whitening or decorrelation is essential for reducing redundancy and minimizing entropy in data compression.
Common techniques for whitening are

Karhunen-Loeve Transform (KLT) / Principal Component Analysis (PCA) / Eigenvalue Decomposition: It transforms data into a space of uncorrelated components. This involves computing the covariance matrix and performing eigenvalue decomposition.

Linear Predictive Coding (LPC): It models the signal as a linear combination of past samples. The whitening filter is derived from the linear prediction coefficients.


The Karhunen-Loeve Transform (KLT), also known as the Karhunen-Loeve Expansion, is a method for decomposing a stochastic process into orthogonal components, which are uncorrelated in both the continuous and discrete domains. Here’s how KLT works in both continuous and diacrete domains
KLT provides an optimal basis for representing continuous signals in terms of uncorrelated components. It decomposes the signal into orthogonal functions, which maximize the variance captured by each component.
Let $X(t)$ be a continuous stochastic process. The autocorrelation function is defined as:
$$
R_X(t_1, t_2) = \mathbb{E}[X(t_1)X(t_2)]
$$
where $R_X(t_1, t_2)$ represents the expected value of the product of the signal at two different times.
Solve the following integral equation to find the eigenfunctions $\varphi_k(t)$ and the corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_k$:
$$
\int R_X(t_1, t_2) \varphi_k(t_2) \, dt_2 = \lambda_k \varphi_k(t_1)
$$
Here, $\varphi_k(t)$ are the orthogonal functions, and $\lambda_k$ are the variances of the components.
The stochastic process $X(t)$ can be expressed as a series expansion in terms of the orthogonal functions:
$$
X(t) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \alpha_k \varphi_k(t)
$$
where $\alpha_k$ are uncorrelated random variables with zero mean and variance $\lambda_k$. To whiten the signal, normalize the coefficients by their standard deviations:
$$
\tilde{\alpha}_k = \frac{\alpha_k}{\sqrt{\lambda_k}}
$$
The whitened signal is then:
$$
\tilde{X}(t) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\tilde{\alpha}_k \varphi_k(t)
$$
This results in a continuous process where the $\tilde{\alpha}_k$ are uncorrelated with unit variance, effectively whitening the signal.
In the discrete domain, KLT can be summarized mathematically as below. Let $\mathbf{X}$ be the data matrix where each row represents a sample.
$$
\hat{\mathbf{R}} = \frac{1}{N} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X}
$$
where $\hat{\mathbf{R}}$ is the sample covariance matrix (assuming $\mathbf{X}$ is zero mean) and $N$ is the number of samples. Applying the eigenvalue decomposition yields
$$
\hat{\mathbf{R}} \mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{\Lambda}
$$
where $\mathbf{Q}$ is the unitary matrix of eigenvectors and $\mathbf{\Lambda}$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues.
Now transform the data into the new basis defined by the eigenvectors:
$$
\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X} \mathbf{Q}
$$
where $\mathbf{Y}$ is the transformed data. Normalize the transformed data by the inverse square root of the eigenvalues:
$$
\mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{Y} \mathbf{\Lambda}^{-1/2} \Rightarrow \mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{X} \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{\Lambda}^{-1/2}
$$
where $\mathbf{Z}$ is the whitened data because
$$
\frac{1}{N}\mathbf{Z}^T\mathbf{Z} = \frac{1}{N}\Lambda^{-T/2}\mathbf{Q}^T\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{\Lambda}^{-1/2} = \mathbf{\Lambda}^{-T/2}\mathbf{Q}^T\underbrace{\frac{1}{N}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}}_{\hat{\mathbf{R}} = \mathbf{Q}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{Q}^T}\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{\Lambda}^{-1/2} = \mathbf{I}
$$
KLT is optimal for linear decorrelation in both continuous and discrete domains, making it powerful for data compression and noise reduction. By focusing on principal components with the highest eigenvalues, KLT can effectively reduce noise. In practice, the whitening transformation can be precomputed using a representative sample of the process, assuming stationarity. This precomputed transformation can then be applied to new data in real-time.
Note that KLT assumes the process is stationary, meaning its statistical properties do not change over time. For non-stationary processes, adaptive methods are required.
